# Protractor test: browser.get clears sessionStorage

Tags: protractor

I'm having a really weird issue with my protractor test. I'm trying to set the right credentials directly on the sessionStorage, but the authentication service doesn't pick up on it. I've isolated it to the following script:

```
describe('The search', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        browser.executeScript(() => {
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('something', JSON.stringify({"test":"test"}));
        });
    });

    it('works when changing URL', () => {
        var result1 = browser.executeScript('return window.sessionStorage.getItem(\'something\')');
        browser.get('/');
        var result2 = browser.executeScript('return window.sessionStorage.getItem(\'something\')');
        expect(result1).toBe(result2);
    });
});
```

The output:

```
1) The search works when changing URL
  Message:
    Expected '{"test":"test"}' to be null.
  Stack:
    Error: Failed expectation
        at Object.<anonymous> (/source/search.spec.ts:12:25)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
```

So as you can see, as soon as `browser.get()` is called, the sessionStorage is cleared. Does anyone have any idea on why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigating to the URL and *then* setting the local storage item worked for me:

```
describe('The search', function () {
    var value = JSON.stringify({"test":"test"});

    beforeAll(function () {
        browser.get('/');
        browser.executeScript(function (value) {
            window.sessionStorage['something'] = value;
        }, value);
    });

    it('works when changing URL', function () {
        var result = browser.executeScript('return window.sessionStorage.getItem(\'something\');');
        expect(value).toEqual(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: This indeed did the trick. I had to add an additional `browser.get('/')` after the executeScript part so that the bootstrap script could pick up on the credentials and forward me to the index page rather than the login page.